# Can I use an ECDH Shared Secret from the same Private / Public Key Pair?

Tags: elliptic-curves, key-reuse, key-generation

I'd like to know if using the ECDH shared secret of a static EC Private Key with it's own corresponding static EC Public Key causes a problem / weakness.

(edit) not asking if it's ok to re-use the keys multiple times.  Static EC Keys are known to be ok in this usage case.

#### Background:

In this environment, several agents are producing and consuming data, and the streams are being protected with static ECDH keys.

The ECDH Shared secret is hashed before it is used as a key in the asymmetric stream cipher. The shared secret will be the same each iteration / connection.

The stream is eventually stored to disk (encrypted)

Typical usage (not considered a problem):
$$
Alice( public ) : \ Q_A = d_A G
$$
$$
Bob( private ) : \ d_B $$
$$
ECDH Secret (Alice Bob) = d_B Q_A = d_B d_A G
$$

Normal so far...

### Question Case:

In some instances, the Producer and Consumer are the same agent, and this ECDH secret devolves into:

$$
ECDH Secret (Alice Alice) = d_A Q_A = d_A d_A G = (d_A)^2G
$$

Is this a problem?

Comment: That's the square computational diffie-hellman problem, which is [equivalent](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.3007&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to the standard computational diffie-hellman problem and hence it's not a problem. Note: Square DH problem: Given $g^x$ and $g$, find $g^{x^2}$ which equals your description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of “*[Reuse of a DH / ECDH public key](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11012/reuse-of-a-dh-ecdh-public-key)*” and/or “*[Is it safe to reuse ECDH asymmetric keys for authentication?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15181/is-it-safe-to-reuse-ecdh-asymmetric-keys-for-authentication)*”.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested duplicates - but those are focused on re-using Keys... my question was asking wether ECDH of Alice's Public Key w/ Alice's Private Key is a weakness.  This is a very different question than can I re-use Alice's Keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not a problem.

What you've found is known as the *square computational diffie-hellman problem*(SCDH) and it can be shown that this is equivalent to the *computational diffie-hellman problem*(CDH).

For completeness:
**SCDH**:
Given $g$ (your $G$) and $g^x$ (your $Q$), find $g^{x^2}$ (your $d_A^2G$).

It is shown [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.3007&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that this problem is as hard as the traditional diffie-hellman problem (below):
**CDH**:
Given $g,g^x,g^y$ find $g^{xy}$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you.